# can't dispose from second page or child page

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, dispose

I can't dispose from second page or child page. The compiler reports: `can not find symbol`

How can I dispose of it?

### `Menu`

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu
     */
    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
    }
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFrame app = new JFrame();
    Task t = new Task();
    t.setVisible(true);
    app.add(t);
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setSize(690, 340);
    app.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}    
}
```

### `Task`

```
public class Task extends javax.swing.JPanel {
/**
 * Creates new form NewJPanel
 */
public Task() {
    initComponents();
}
    private void BackButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    Menu t = new Menu();
    t.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    dispose(); <-- here
    
}    
}
```

I linked from `Menu` to `Task`. It's done but when I go back to `Menu` it can not be disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use a MouseListener to handle a click on a button. Instead you should be using an ActionListener which was designed to be used for this purpose.

Then in your `ActionListener` code you need to get a reference to the frame containing the button before you can dispose of the frame. You can get the button from the `ActionEvent`.

The basic logic would be:

```
JButton button = (JButton)evt.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
window.dispose();
```